# Where Does This Little Plastic Piece go on a ThinkPad Series 3 Docking Station?

Tags: hardware, lenovo

I am setting up a Thinkpad Laptop and Dock for a coworker and there was this little plastic piece that fell off the dock when we took it out of the box. Where does this go? Is it part of the laptop or the dock? It seems like it needs to go somewhere because the laptop rocks back and forth when it's placed in the dock.

[image: Front view of plastic piece]
[image: Back view of plastic piece]

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that this snaps into the top-right corner of the dock, and keeps the laptop stable:
[image: Where the plastic piece goes in the top-right corner of the dock]